# Spark for python - Null when cast it from string to decimals(36,12)

Tags: python, apache-spark

Unable to convert String to decimal and it returns null.

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
    df=spark.read("default.data_table")
    df2=df.column("invoice_amount",df["invoice_amount"].cast('decimal(36,12)'))
    //display(df)
    display(df2)
```

invoice_amount as "15860461.48"(string) in the table data_table

If i print df - it shows the invoice amount as "15860461.48", but when i print df2, it shows null

Comment: A string isn't a number, you need to *parse* it to get the numeric value

Answer (score 0):

What version did you use? In my case, it works well where I have used the spark 3.0.1.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = ['15860461.48']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, StringType())

df.show(truncate=False)

df2 = df.withColumn('value', col('value').cast('decimal(36, 12)'))
df2.show(truncate=False)

+-----------+
|value      |
+-----------+
|15860461.48|
+-----------+

+---------------------+
|value                |
+---------------------+
|15860461.480000000000|
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Lamanus. My version is Apache Spark 2.4.3. That's correct, it works if i create the dataframe manually, but if i read it from the table it does not.

Comment: Can you post any DDL or db table schema? What type of database? is that really work with `spark.read("table")`? without jdbc?

Comment: create table data_table(invoice_amount string comment,material_id string)using paraquet. We are creating this table from the dataframe.   f_sales.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("data_table");